# Rosbridge PNG decompression in Obj-C/C++

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use rosbridge/websocket for an iOS project. I want to use the PNG compression option for image transfers but cannot figure out how to implement this "hack" of decompressing the PNG data in Objective C (C++ should also be ok) .

Is there any alternative compression method in rosbridge e.g. gzip?
If not, how would you go about implementing the PNG decompression in Objective C (or perhaps C++)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199785/rosbridge-png-decompression-in-obj-c/c++/) by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have opencv (it's ported to iOS) you can use cv::imdecode (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imencode#imdecode). It works same like cv::imread for reading+decoding png/jpg etc. data from files with the difference  takes not a file but a  binary buffer e. g. `std::vector<uchar>`  as input for decoding...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2